# If child page has content, enable link, else disable link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am working on a mosaic of thumbnails linking to child pages. The code works in such a way that the child pages display in an iframe overlaying the content. However the client wants only 4 of these pages to have content, so the code needs to work in such a way that ONLY if the child page has content, does the rollover get enabled to open as an iframe overlay.

I currently have the following code. Any ideas how i could customise it so that the overlay is enabled ONLY if the child page has content? Many thanks.

```
<section id="content" role="main">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <section id="content_team" class="entry-content js-masonry">
                    <?php $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = " . $post->ID . " AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT'); ?>
                    <?php if ($child_pages) : foreach ($child_pages as $pageChild) : setup_postdata($pageChild); ?>
                            <div class="child-thumb"> 
                                <div id="click_overlay" onclick="var overlay = document.getElementById('hidden_overlay');
                                        overlay.src = 'about:blank';
                                        overlay.style.display = 'block';
                                        overlay.src = '<?php echo get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>';"><span class="featured-title-overlay">
                                        <span class="featured-title">
                                            <span class="title"><?php echo get_the_title($pageChild->ID); ?></span>
                                            <div class="hr">&nbsp;</div>
                                            <span class="title_link">Read more...</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID); ?></div>
                                <br class="clear" />
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach;
                    endif;
                    ?>
                </section>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile;
    endif; ?>
    <iframe id="hidden_overlay" src="about:blank"></iframe> 
    <p class="clear">&nbsp;</p>
</section>
```

Comment: What are the conditions of a link "without content"? Will it give an HTTP 404 error? Will the response body be empty? Will it depend on the existence of some element in the <body> of the child page?

Comment: Thanks for getting back - no, it should just not display a rollover if the child page doesn't have any content. The condition is that it should recognize that the child page has no content filled in the content field.

Comment: My question was "What, exactly, does 'doesn't have any content' mean in your case?"

Comment: Ok won't let me paste the child page code. There is a block in the child page, it should recognise that this block of code has no content in the back-end. 

<?php the_block('Bio'); ?>